# gcp terraform - how to connect pubsub_topic to budget

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I have managed to create pubsub_topic and budget with terraform in GCP. How could I connect pubsub_topic with a budget?

I have following code:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name    = "alert_topic"
  project = "my_project"
}

resource "google_billing_budget" "global-budget" {
(...)
  all_updates_rule {
    pubsub_topic = "projects/my_project/topics/alert_topic"
  }
```

terraform apply creates the topic and the budget. However they are not connected as seen in the GUI. (example picture showing which section I WOULD LIKE to be done terraform and currently is NOT done:
[image]

Comment: all_updates_rule should serve ur purpose..

Comment: well, its strange though because terraform apply with no errors, creates budget and pubsub, but the checkbox "connect a Pub/Sub topic to this budget" is not being checked. If I check it by hand, then I can select manually the pubsub from the list.

Comment: are updates being sent to ur topic without checking this box. have u tried that?

Comment: will try to trigger this an check. Should ```gcloud pubsub topics list-subscriptions alert_topic``` return something? What is the meaning of pubsub topic subscriprion?